# How can I Insert the value null to a database column with ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I Insert the value null to a database column with ruby code?
I'm using a rails application.

Comment: What does the table definition look like in your schema.rb?

Answer (score 6):

```
user.title = nil
user.save
```

Comment: I tried to save the value nil to the database but the database saves the value 'on'.. Is this some ruby related problem?

Comment: depend how you column is define.

Answer (score 0):

As shingara said or:

```
user.update_attribute(:title, nil)
```